# Ubuntu 18.04 with sudden filling of the disk

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, hard-drive-failure

My problem:
I was using Ubuntu 18.04 as normal and then suddenly it popped that i am left with few MB's out of 497GB.
My 1 TB hard drive is divided into two partition one is having 497 GB and the rest is above 500 GB and  the main boot folder is in the 497 GB partition.
Then I checked that I am left with only 0 byte out of 497 GB.
I tried to force reboot my machine by holding the power button key and when it started the reboot it froze at the point of mount ... etc.
Kindly help me what should I do.

Comment: I'd boot from a live CD, and inspect the contents of the disk. it will help a lot to know where the space is being used. Have you set up filesystem snapshots or anything like that?

Comment: @FrankThomas no I did not made any snapshot.

Comment: @FrankThomas It will be very helpful if you guide me after insert the Live CD.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty in Ubuntu there is an app - disk usage analyser ; use it to see why your are out of storage ; https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429/314322

Comment: I would do as Madhubala suggests, boot from an unbutu live CD, Mount the volume, and use disk usage analyzer to look for folders that have abnormally large volumes of data. From there you'll want to research what gets stored at the locatiton, and try to determine why your system went out of whack.